# how can i update first then send the email with one button?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, apex-code, oracle-apex-5.1

for example, in the model dialog, when i changed the date and click the send email button.
first, i need to update the informations then run the send email process,

to be clear, i want to give you demo what i want to achieve,

first i open the model dialog and then change some names or dates
after i want to click the send email button,  send email button should update the informations first and then run the process (send email process).

i tried a few dynamic actions, i made two process, first one row processing with condition when button sendmail and second one send email process when button send email.

[this is my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyzdU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it looks as if

- `SEND EMAIL` button should **submit** page (which will also save changes you've made)

  - set "Database action" property to "SQL UPDATE action"
- create a **process** which sends mail and runs when `SEND EMAIL` button is pressed